# Mail Attachment not send when using Cron

Tags: drupal

Email Attachment is sent correctly when I call my function by visiting the   url that I set with the hook menu

EX :When I visit /admin/config/send the hook_menu will call main() method and send the email with the attachment.

but when I call  the same function main() from inside the hook_cron() the mail is sent(body and message is set) but not with the attachment :

```
function hook_cron(){
    main();
}
```

Comment: Try to change `main()` to `sendMailWithAttachment()` method. If it not helps, paste us some more code, maybe this one which sends mail.

Comment: Sounds like user permission voodoo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have to ensure the cron is executed with an authenticated/admin user loaded.

In Drupal 8 this would be like following ([source](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/233854/15055)).

```
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

/**
 * Implements hook_cron().
 */
function my_module_cron() {
  // Login as user 1
  $user = User::load(1);
  user_login_finalize($user);

  // Your custom cron functions

  // Login as user 0 (anonymous)
  $user = User::load(0);
  user_login_finalize($user);
}
```